# How to keep remote directory up-to-date with local directory automatically?

Tags: centos, rsync

Say, I have a directory A on my local machine and B on remote machine(Both are CentOS 7). I am using **rsync** to sync between them. But I want to track my changes on local directory and automatically update the remote directory. And may be, I want to execute some additional command on remote.

I know, I can run a cronjob in each minute to run rsync and other commands, or even run a script with systemd and reboot remote each time I update my local directory. But clearly, those are nasty solutions.

Any better idea?

Comment: Have you thought about using `watch`?

Comment: Can we have more information or explanation on you comment